# Using selenium How to move mouse pointer?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have faced a problem while trying to move mouse pointer form around a line of text in a text area.

**Detail of my problem:**

I have a line of text inside a text area and that text area contain a 'markdown' tab for external link. when I click on that markdown tab I get `[](http://)` line inside text area. And mouse pointer is currently inside `[]` brace and I have write something there. So current pointer position is inside `[]` brace and if I write 'Googel' inside it, then its looks like  `[Google | ](http://)`

**My Problem Is:**

How can I move that pointer to write something after `(http://)`

like this`[Google](http://www.google.com)`

Comment: Just a thought (as I don't know Ruby). In Java, you can [easily simulate pressing left arrow](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html), so your solution in Java (assuming `elem` is a valid WebElement instance) would be `elem.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT + 'www.google.com')`. Got the idea?

Comment: What is your test trying to test? Would it not be equivalent to just type the full "\[Google\]\(http://www.google.com)" into the text area?

Comment: Is this textbox with special functions a third party thing, or something your own people wrote, if it's from a third party code library, why waste time testing their stuff? is that what you are being paid for?  just set the value you need for your test and move on.  If you actually need to functionally test this editor, then learn about using sendkeys (it's supported by watir-webdriver) to move the cursor around and enter specific characters as needed

Comment: @Chuck van der Linden Thank you a lot.   [send_key](http://watirwebdriver.com/sending-special-keys/) solve my problem.